# Passing dataframe from one code to another

Tags: r

I am preparing an extensive report which pulls data from various source and merge them. For fetching data from each source i am using a separate R file. These files need to interact with each other(passing date ranges and resulting data frames).
To pass the date range from my main.R file to the fetch_data.R file i am using

```
system("cmd.exe", input = paste('"C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.3.2\\bin\\Rscript.exe" "Rcodes\\Audit\\fetch_data.R"',
                                arg1=start_date,
                                arg2=end_date))
```

Once fetch_data.R receives the dates i get the resulting dataframe table_1 from fetch_data.R.
I need to pass table_1 from fetch_data.R to my original main.R and carry on with remaining code in main.R.

Comment: Never use scripts to replace functions. Why don't you make a function `fetch_data` and call it in `main.R`?

Comment: I guess that would have been a better approach

Comment: "These files need to interact with each other(passing date ranges and resulting data frames)." aiyayaaaaai yaaaaai

Comment: What is the question?